# How can I make Apache Spark workers to import libraries before running map

Tags: python, nginx, parallel-processing, apache-spark, traffic-measurement

I wanted to make a traffic report on country from nginx access.log file. This is my code snippet using Apache Spark on Python:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonAccessLogAnalyzer")
    def get_country_from_line(line):
        try:
            from geoip import geolite2
            ip = line.split(' ')[0]
            match = geolite2.lookup(ip)
            if match is not None:
                return match.country
            else:
                return "Unknown"
        except IndexError:
            return "Error"

    rdd = sc.textFile("/Users/victor/access.log").map(get_country_from_line)
    ips = rdd.countByValue()

    print ips
    sc.stop()
```

On a 6GB log file, it took an hour to complete the task (I ran on my Macbook Pro, 4 cores) which is too slow. I think the bottle neck is that whenever spark maps a line, it has to import `geolite2` which has to load some database I think. **Is there anyway for me to import `geolite2` on each worker instead of each line?** Would it boost the performance? Any suggestion to improve that code?

Answer (score 0):

What about using broadcast variables? [Here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) is the doc which explains how they work. However they are simply read-only variables which are spread to all worker nodes once per worker and then accessed whenever necessary.

Comment: I already tried broadcasting it but it didn't work. I think the geolite2 contains too many references to complex objects.

Comment: Please have a look at my gist: https://gist.github.com/tranvictor/fc5e7338abd4fdaffedc

Comment: Ok, now it is clear, it manages internally threads so references to them cannot be broadcasted. Well, actually what you need is a map between an ip address and a geo location. Then, I think that the simplest solution is trying finding one and use it as a broadcast variable if you can....